# Calculate the surface area of this shape.

Tags: area

I am stuck at calculating the surface area for this shape (only red area).
I know how to calculate some area, but not sure how to substract area

[image]

$$P = \frac{20 \cdot 10}2 = 100 - 25\pi\, -\, ?$$

Comment: I suspect that's the highschool chaining notation; give a kid $12+5+23$ and he'll do $12+5=17+23=40$, meaning, $[12+5=17][17+23=40]$

Comment: You want the red area or the area marked by the red arrow?

Comment: I want the red area

Comment: I need to get surface of area marked only in red. As I said, I don't know how to substract area marked by the red arrow. Or there is another way to get surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segment $x$ is twice $y$ because the rectangle base is twice the height.

The second equation is Pythagora's Theorem

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 x=2 y \\
 (5-x)^2+(5-y)^2=25 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

we get $(5-2y)^2+(5-y)^2=25$

$y^2-6 y+5=0 \to y_1=1;\;y_2=5$

$x=2;\;y=5$ is the point where diagonal and circle intersect

So we have $\sin\alpha=\frac{3}{5}$

The area $\mathcal{S}$ we are calculating is composed by the green triangle and the pink curved part. The pink part is the trapezoid less the sector with angle $\alpha$

$$\mathcal{S}=\frac{2\times 1}{2}+\left(\frac{3\times(1+5)}{2}-\frac{25 \pi }{\arcsin\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)}\right)\approx 1.95624$$

Hope this is useful
$$
.
$$
[image]